# Type-annotate but skip class attributes in an auto_attribs class

Tags: python, python-typing, python-attrs

I am currently designing a class structure using `attrs`. It is a tree-like structure where I need a parent backlink for certain purposes. OTOH, I want to use frozen classes (there are cached properties, which rely on read-only state).

This means that the tree must be instantiated bottom-up, child-before parent. To solve this, I invented a special kind of weakref object, which can be lazy-bound exactly once.

```
class LateRef(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ref: Optional[T] = None

    def set(self, obj: T):
        if self.ref is not None:
            raise RuntimeError('Reference can only be set once.')
        self.ref = weakref.ref(obj)

    def __call__(self) -> Optional[T]:
        if self.ref is None:
            return None
        return self.ref()
```

There is custom initialization code to create an unbound reference in the child, and bind them in the parent:

```
@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, frozen=True)
class Child:
    some_attribute:str = "whatever"
   
    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.__dict__['parent'] = LateRef()

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, frozen=True)
class Parent:
    children: List[Child] = attr.ib(converter=_deepclone) # off-screen :-)
    
    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        for child in self.children:
            child.parent.set(self)
```

I need to sneak in the `Child.parent` attribute through the backdoor due to the frozenness of `child`. Previously I put it as a class attribute with custom factory, but then it is turned into an `attrs`-attribute, which it really shouldn't be. E.g. I don't want the `parent` to turn up in hashing, comparison, str representation and so on.

The code is already working, BUT: As you see I would like to do things right and type-annotate as far as possible. Putting the `parent` directly in the `__dict__` means that the usual tools don't know the expected type. In fact they might even complain that the `parent` attribute doesn't exist at all.

Long story short question: Is there a way to declare `parent` as class attribute with type annotation, while telling `attr.s` to skip / ignore it? Or is there another solution I am overlooking?

Edit: i.e. How to make a static type checker recognize the `parent` attribute's type, without making it an `attr.ib`.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is to bypass the frozen-ness of a frozen class, I’d suggest to take the same route as `attrs` in its `__init__` methods and use [`object.__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) directly. `attrs` classes are always frozen, so we have to work around it too.

Might not be the most elegant way, but Python sadly isn’t really designed for immutability, so we have to work with what we have.

That said, your `_deepclone` converter seems to indicate that you don’t need/want to add the original objects to the Parent? In that case [`attr.evolve()`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.evolve) is the perfect tool for you.

P.S. you can write just `@attr.frozen` now. `auto_attribs` is True by default. See https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#next-generation-apis

Comment: ``object.__setattr__`` and ``object.__dict__ = ...`` are in my view two different ways of expressing the same. Both have the problem that a static type checker won't pick up that there is a ``.parent()`` property with type ``Parent``.
The ``_deepclone`` converter has exactly the purpose to clear out the parent reference upon construction. Since i might be giving ``Child`` objects already attached to another root node.
I actuall use ``evolve`` for cloning already - didn't include this in the sample :-)

Comment: You just want `parent: Parent = attr.field(init=False)` then?

Comment: (`__setattr__` has the upside of working with slotted classes btw :))

Comment: That's what I had previously. But this makes parent appear in str representation, compare, asdict(), ... - which makes me feel that there might be a better solution. Hmm. maybe one should just turn auto_attribs off and explicitly mark actual attr.ibs....

Comment: Hm, can’t help with asdict (you can block is out there tho) but the rest you can set to False too.

Comment: Just had another idea, which might be "it". Add a property returning a ``LateRef()``, and decorate it with ``@functools.cached_property``. This way it is clearly not part of the classes "own data" but can be type-annotated just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I settled on: (Thanks @hynek for the discussion and your awesome work!)

```
@attr.frozen(slots=False)
class Child:
    some_attribute:str = "whatever"
   
    @functools.cached_property
    def parent(self) -> LateRef["Parent"]:
        return LateRef()

# Parent class stays the same
```

Works nearly the same (`parent` is stored as `__dict__["parent"]` on first access), and is understood flawlessly at least by VSCode.